# I am not getting output. When I enter the number of books it crashes.. I don't know why!!! I am new C

Tags: c

While reading structure I tried to implement following program. I am not getting the output. As I enter number of books after compilation, it crashes and says return value 23332232434(around). I am using dev c ++ 5.8.... Plz help me out..

```
# include<stdio.h>

void main()

{

    struct book
    {
        char name[20];
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
    //struct book *ptr;
    int num=0,i=0;
    printf("How much books you have !  \n");
    scanf("%i",num);
    printf("%d \n ",num);
    struct book a[num];
    //num=5;

    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter name: \n");
        gets(a[i].name);
        printf("price: \n");
        scanf("%f",&a[i].price);
        printf("pages : \n");
        scanf("%d",&a[i].pages);
    }
    printf("Name \t\t price \t pages \t\n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \t\t %f \t %d \t\n",a[i].name,a[i].price,a[i].pages);
    }
    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `scanf("%d",&num);` for integer use `%d`.

Comment: What tutorial still teaches `gets()`... :S

Comment: "I am new C" - so you are a new programming language? that's sweet.

Comment: What tutorial teaches `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a segmentation fault because you give an invalid argument to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d",&num); // Give the address of the variable you want to set
```

By the way, you should use:

```
int main(void)
```